# Nested 4 loop with arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, amazon-web-services, nested-loops

I almost have this but it seems not to want to do the regions correctly.  this script should loop through each region for each profile in profiles array.  For instance I want to loop through us-east-1 for the prod profile which will drop its output to prod.csv then the same with preprod and dev.  then I want it to loop through the second index of the regions array us-east-2 for all of the profiles and so on.  My scrip seems to only populate the prod.csv file but only a few lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm test/*.csv

declare -a profiles=("preprod" "dev" "prod")
declare -a regions=("us-east-1" "us-east-2" "us-west-1")
for x in "${regions[@]}" ; do
        for i in "${profiles[@]}"; do

aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, LaunchTime, Placement.AvailabilityZone, Placement.Tenancy, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [1][0], [Tags[?Key==`servername`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`stack`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`CostCenter`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`business-unit`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`RI`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`RI Expire`].Value] [0][0] ]' > test/"$i".csv --profile "$i" --region "$x"
        done
done
```

Comment: `> test/"$i".csv` says to overwrite the file so each time you call `aws` you're wiping out anything written by previous passes through the loop; instead of the `aws` call try `echo "$x $i : aws > test/$i.csv"` to see how many times each .csv is overwritten; one *easy* fix would be to delete(rm) the 3x .csv files before the `for` loops and then `>> test/"$i".csv`

Comment: Thanks for the reply -markp-fuso,  the loop does create all 3 csv files, but dev and preprod are empty and only prod has a few lines.  I can see what you are saying though.  Let me give it a try and will post back.

Comment: does the `prod` output file contain actual `prod` data or just garbage?  I'm not familiar with this `aws` command so fwiw ... perhaps move the `>> text/"$i".csv` to the end of the line (after `--profile "$i" --region "$x"`)

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, I'm such an idiot lol.  The append does work and in my original script that had hundreds of lines because I did not use loops, I did use the >> (append) to each file.  Ugh don't know how I missed that.  Thank you so much for your help -markp-fuso.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you -markp-fuso for your help.  All that was needed was to append writing to the files using **>>**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceType, State.Name, LaunchTime, Placement.AvailabilityZone, Placement.Tenancy, PrivateIpAddress,[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value] [1][0], [Tags[?Key==`servername`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`stack`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`CostCenter`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`business-unit`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`RI`].Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key==`RI Expire`].Value] [0][0] ]' >> test/"$i".csv --profile "$i" --region "$x"
        done
done
```